# Enable Developer mode on Tizen TV 2016 [KU6300]

Tags: tizen, television

I have a Samsung Tizen TV 2016 model KU6300. As per [samsungdforum](https://www.samsungdforum.com/tizenguide/tizen3511/index.html#How-to-set-%22Developer-Mode%22-in-the-TV) it can enabled by pressing keys 12345 in remote. But I have a model where only smart remote is available. No numbers keys in this remote.

[image: Smart remote]

What is the procedure to enable developer mode on this TV?

Comment: Did you try to go to  "Apps" panel  -> press 123 number pad on your smart remote -> and select 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 from number strip appeared on the screen?

Comment: there is no number pad on smart remote

Comment: Yeap, that's why I said to use the on screen number strip.

Comment: thanks a lot..it dint strike me at first. i am able to do it now.

Comment: btw - you can connect USB keyboard to the TV

Answer (score 8):

In this remote, place where 123 is written that opens up a number keypad on Smart TV.

Thus, follow the steps given below :

1. Go to **Apps** Screen.
2. Click **123** from remote.
3. Number keypad gets open up -> Enter **12345**  from it and then done.
4. A popup asking for IP gets open up.
5. Enter IP address of your system (using the same procedure - clicking on 123 from remote).
6. Now, connect with the IP (**TV IP**) in your IDE and execute your build.

Comment: After entered ip address, click OK and a pop up appears telling you should reboot your TV. Once I restarted, nothing happens. In previous models, a msg appears on Apps section indicating DEVELOPER MODE in red letters. No need to say that Tizen IDE can't establish connection with TV.

Comment: Somehow, changes are not applied until you reboot the TV. To do this, is not enough turn it off from remote control. You need to remove the power chord for 2 min, and then reconnect.

Comment: @grahamo'donnel You save me, one day trying to connnect IDE with TV, rebooting many times. This should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of these things worked for me, but I found a solution. I have a 2018 Samsung Q6FN 65 inch TV with Tizen OS. I could not get the developer panel to come up using the remote and the 123 button and subsequent number selection panel. I also don't know how to get a number pad to come up using the remote that came with this TV. However, I used the Smarthings app on my Android phone. I then connected with the TV and clicked on the remote icon at the bottom of the screen. This brings up another screen where I toggled the 123 icon to on. This brings up a number pad!!!!! With this number pad I entered 1 2 3 4 5 and the developer panel came up where I turned on developer mode and entered the IP address for my computer. This effect took place immediately without turning the TV off and on. 
Hope this is clear and helps someone. BP